# Return output from Java

Tags: java

*Disclaimer: Java is not a language that  I know very well.*
I am working on a project for a identity platform. I am trying to retrieve a list of entitlements via the entitlement class, but I am not able to output any data when calling my function. Below is the code that I currently have.

```
import sailpoint.api.SailPointContext;
import sailpoint.tools.Util;
import sailpoint.object.*;
import sailpoint.api.*;
import sailpoint.workflow.*;
import java.util.*;    

  QueryOptions ops = new QueryOptions();  //This creates the Query Options
  ops.addFilter(Filter.eq("identity.name", "UserNAME")); //Defines the Identity / IdentityName that we are searching for

  Iterator itr = context.search(IdentityEntitlement.class, ops, "id"); //Java iterator is an interface belongs to collection framework allow us to traverse the collection and access the data element of collection without bothering the user about specific implementation of that collection it. Basically List and set collection provides the iterator. You can get Iterator from ArrayList, LinkedList, and TreeSet etc. 
  while (null != itr && itr.hasNext()) { //Run this this iteration while not null
    String id = ((Object[]) itr.next())[0].toString(); //collect the object as a string
    IdentityEntitlement identEnt = context.getObjectById(IdentityEntitlement.class, id); //define the IdentityEntitlement from (IdentityEntitlement.class, id);
    System.out.println("identEnt: "+identEnt.toXml()); //Print the results
  }
  Util.flushIterator(itr); //End the Iterator
```

Comment: It would be great if you [format your code first](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44722411/edit)

Comment: There's no method defined. What "function" are you calling? And if this is the code inside the "function" (they are called methods in Java) there's no `return` statement which would indicate something is being returned to the calling action.

Comment: Thanks for fixing that for me Gilad. It is actually this: itr &&: This is a gotcha specific to beanshell.

Answer (score 1):

One reason the output is not showing is because it is not entering the while() loop.

I think some correction needs to be done in the while() condition

```
while(itr.hasNext())
   String id = ((Object[]) itr.next())[0].toString();
   IdentityEntitlement identEnt =     context.getObjectById(IdentityEntitlement.class, id); 
   System.out.println("identEnt: "+identEnt.toXml());
```

if you do this, you'll probably get the result you're looking for.

Please check if that helps !

Comment: Would the return object then be   Return IdentityEntitlement identEnt ?

Comment: @jmsahearn I have edited the answer, please check it now.

Comment: @julianffI am getting a BeanShell error, but making progress.